# Autoscaling Stateless MIG while retaining instance names

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a process that needs to be auto-scaled and new instances need to be of a specific format.  I've found documentation that says this can be done via an MIG but very little information on how to accomplish this:

Basically right now each of our instances in our stateless MIG pops up as -xxxx where the xxxx is a 4 digit random alphanumeric string.  We would like to create a pool of instance names it can pull from when auto-scaling.

[The section of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryeSt.png) which I believe shows that stateless instances can retain their instance name.
(From https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs)

[Screenshot of the section of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwtBK.png) which gives some more information but no specific instructions.  I've tried working with this but new instances that are added via auto-scaling are still given generic names.
(From https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/working-with-managed-instances#adding_instances_with_specific_names)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the documentation related to name specification during a managed instance creation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/working-with-managed-instances#adding_instances_with_specific_names)

Do not hesitate if you have a specific question.